# inputField required is not working LWC

Tags: lightning, lightning-web-components

I have a Custom modal with `lightning-input` and `lightning-input-field`  on click on save button have to validate the input fields is mandatory.

`lightning-input-field` is pick list values

For `lightning-input` by adding the below code It validate me in client side and shows the error box adding class`slds-has-error`.

```
 const allValid = [  ...this.template.querySelectorAll("lightning-input")
].reduce((validSoFar, inputCmp) => {
 inputCmp.reportValidity();
 return validSoFar && inputCmp.checkValidity();
 }, true);
```

for `lighting -input fields` even though the pick list value is not selected, when we click save button the controller method `createParentGuardian` is called, Client Side validation is not happening. `required` parameter is added in `lighting -input fields`.

Can you please help me on this.

HTML

```
 <section role="dialog" tabindex="-1" class="slds-modal slds-fade-in-open slds-modal_large"
                            aria-labelledby="modal-heading-01" aria-modal="true"
                            aria-describedby="modal-content-id-1">
                            <div class="slds-modal__container" style="width: 50%;">

                                <div class="slds-modal__content slds-p-around_medium"
                                    id="modal-content-id-1-addparent" style="height: 65%;">

                                    <lightning-record-edit-form object-api-name="Contact">
                                        <div class="demo-only demo-only--sizing slds-grid slds-wrap">
                                            <div class="slds-size_2-of-4 ">
                                                <div class="slds-text-align_center slds-m-around_x-small">
                                                    <lightning-input label="First Name" value={firstname}
                                                        onchange={handleChange} name="firstname"
                                                        message-when-value-missing="First Name is Missing" required>
                                                    </lightning-input>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>

                                            <div class="slds-size_2-of-2">
                                                <div class="slds-text-align_center slds-m-around_x small">
                                                    <lightning-input-field field- name="Student_Relation__c"
                                                        onchange={handleChange} name="relationship" required>
                                                    </lightning-input-field>

                                                </div>
                                            </div>

                                        </div>
                                    </lightning-record-edit-form>

                                </div>
                                <footer class="slds-modal__footer">
                                    <lightning-button label="Cancel" variant="neutral"
                                        onclick={closeStudentParentModal}>
                                    </lightning-button>
                                    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                                    <lightning-button type="submit" variant="brand" value="AddParent"
                                        name="AddParent" label="Save" onclick= 
                                    {handleonClickParentSave}>
                                    </lightning-button>
                                </footer>
                            </div>
                        </section>
```

JS:

```
 handleonClickParentSave() {

const allValid = [
  ...this.template.querySelectorAll("lightning-input")
].reduce((validSoFar, inputCmp) => {
  inputCmp.reportValidity();
  return validSoFar && inputCmp.checkValidity();
}, true);


createParentGuardian({
  firstName: this.firstname,
  lastName: this.lastName,
  phone: this.phone,
  email: this.email,
  studentRelation: this.relationship,
  enrollmentName: this.recordId
})
  .then(result => {
    this.returnResult = result;
    console.log("this.returnResult --> " + this.returnResult);
    if (result) {
      console.log("result1 -->" + this.returnResult);
      this.variant = "success";
      this.title = "Success";
      this.message = "Sucessfully Created";
      this.closeStudentParentModal();
    } else {
      console.log("result1 Else -->" + this.returnResult);
      this.variant = "error";
      this.title = "Error";
      this.message = "Failed to Create";
    }
  })
  .catch(error => {
    this.returnResult = false;
    if (error) {
      console.log("result2 -->" + this.returnResult);
      this.variant = "error";
      this.title = "Error";
      this.message = error;
    }
    console.log("error -->" + error);
  });

}
```

Comment: I guess you have to set required="true".

Comment: tried that too, `LWC1037: To set a boolean attributes, try <lightning-input-field required> instead of <lightning-input-field required="true">`

Answer (score 4):

You need to understand the **required** attribute of the [lightning-input-field](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-input-field/documentation) component.

1. To make an input field required on the server, mark the field Required in Setup. Input fields set as required on the server are universally required, to be displayed with a red asterisk wherever the input fields are used.
2. To make an input field required on the client only, include the required attribute in lightning-input-field. Use this attribute if you want to require a value in a field before the form can be submitted, and the field isn't marked required in Setup. If the field doesn't have a value, the component's client-side validation catches the error before the form data is submitted to the server.

> In your case, you are using custom handler to save the record using
>   **onclick** event, not the lightning data service one, So what happens is when you click the button, your **handleonClickParentSave** method
>   gets called first, then lightning data service standard methods gets
>   called to validate the form and submit the form.

What you have to do is:-

For lightning-input-field, if you want to validate your field dynamically on button click, You can do like:-

```
this.template.querySelector('lightning-input-field').reportValidity();
```

reportValidity() method validate the field in lightning-input-field.If there is no issue, then only you call your apex method.

> Note:- Also as you are using the lightning-record-edit-form, you need
>   to prevent the form to be submitted via its standard functionality as
>   you are overiding it with cutsom apex controller method.

To do so, define **onsubmit** event and prevent it from submitting to the server.

```
handleSubmit(event){
   event.preventDefault();       // stop the form from submitting
}
```

and

```
<lightning-record-edit-form object-api-name="Contact" onsubmit={handleSubmit}>
</lightning-record-edit-form>
```